# Eigen Value of differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

How can I find eigenvalue and eigenvector of the following:

$$Sp(x)= p''(x)-2xp'(x)$$

In class we only covered matrices for eigenvector. I have no clue how to approach differential equation. Someone please help.

Comment: The definition of eigenvector and eigenvalue is similar in this context: you need to find a non-zero function p(x) (often called an eigenfunction) satisfying $Sp(x) = \lambda p(x)$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: hey..i have tried with p(x)=1+x+x^2. And got Sp(x)= -4x^2-2x+2.. is the eigen vector (2,-2,-4). thank you!

Comment: That $S(p(x))=-4x^2-2x+2$ is not proportional with a $\lambda$ to $p(x)=1+x+x^2$. So that is not an eigenvector.

Comment: Do you have to get all of the eigenvectors for this problem?

Comment: It is fairly likely that the problem is intended for the vector space of polynomials with a fixed degree bound (usually 2 or 3), and real coefficients.

Comment: no actually just.. S ∈ L(P2(R)

Comment: @Misha  What does P2(R)) mean? Oh, to reply to me, start your comment with an @ sign and at least the first three letters of my user name... Everyone who looks will be able to read the comment, but I will get a little notification, even if I am looking at other questions instead

Comment: @WillJagy oh sorry.. it just means S belongs to polynomial(P) of degree 2 in R(Real number field

Comment: In that case, you might as well take a fixed basis of "vectors" $1,x,x^2.$ Calculate what $S$ does to each of these. For each vector, the column of the matrix are the coefficients of what $S$ does to it... Then you want, finally, the eigenvalues of that matrix, and the eigenvectors (which are of the form $a + b x + c x^2 $)

Comment: Let's see, you can also ignore matrices here. Just take $p(x) = a + bx + c x^2,$ carefully calculate $p'' - 2x p',$ and figure out when this is a real constant times the original $p(x).$ If this happens only when $a=b=c=0$ we say there are no (real) eigenvalues. But I would guess there are some

Comment: @WillJagy when i hit S with p(x)=a+bx+cx^2, i get 2c-2bx-4cx^2. now i dont know what to do next?

Comment: In general, try to show your work/your thoughts about the question. See [this]("no clue" questions? - Mathematics Meta - Stack Exchange
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com › ...
) for the communities view on 'no clue' questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
S 1 = 0\\
S x = -2 x\\
S x^2 = 2-4x^2\\
 = 2*1 + 0*x + (-4)*x^2
$$

If you let $p(x)=1$, you get $Sp(x) = 0 = 0*p(x)$ so $\lambda=0$ for the eigenvector $p(x)=1$.

Another one is also apparent already. Let $p(x)=x$, you get $Sp(x)=-2x$, so $\lambda=-2$ for the eigenvector $p(x)=x$.

Put the matrix together in this basis $\{ 1,x,x^2\}$

$$
S = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -4\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This is the matrix you seek to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for. There are the two that we've already found. The only one left will turn out to be $\lambda=-4$ with $p(x)=-1+0*x+2*x^2$. In that case $Sp(x)=4-8x^2=(-4)*p(x)$.