# What is differential operator and what is this notation in my book? Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have attached a screenshot in my textbook that I do not understand:

[image]

So some examples of C'[a, b] mibht be say 2x, 2x^2, 3x^4 because they all have derivatives (found by power rule) that are continuous from any two points and b right?

What is the difference between C'[a,b] and C[a,b]? How is $D_x$ a linear transformation between the two? What is $D_x$?

Answer (score 1):

The Author is denoting with $C'[a,b]$ and $C[a,b]$ the vector spaces for the linear transfomation $D_x$ that is

$$D_x: C'[a,b]\to C[a,b]$$

notably $D_x$ is the derivative operator, that is for $x^2 \in C'[a,b]$

$$D_x(x^2)=(x^2)'=2x\in C[a,b]$$

and

- $C'[a,b]$ is the vector (sub)space of the differentiable functions on $[a,b]$
- $C[a,b]$ is the vector (sub)space continuos functions on $[a,b]$

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about it too long. Almost any problem that will be asked of you will be about polynomials, with a bound on the degree.

This is a good example: [Eigen Value of differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912677/eigen-value-of-differential-equation)